# Как вынести логику и избавиться от дублирования?React дублирование componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть два компонента. В зависимости от условия в контейнере рендюрю один из нихНо логика у этих компонентах повторяется
Особенно метод componentWillReseiveProps   у них одинаковый и выглядит примерно так

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const { inputType: nextInputType } = nextProps;
const { inputType, values } = this.props;

const { message: nextMessage } = this.getDefaultValues(nextProps.values);

const { message } = this.getDefaultValues(values);

const hasNotChangedInput = nextInputType === inputType;
const hasNotChangedValue = nextMessage === message;

if (hasNotChangedValue && hasNotChangedInput) return;

if (nextInputType === PHONE_STEP_INPUT_MESSAGE) {

    this.handleMessageInputType(nextMessage, nextInputType);
} else if (nextInputType === PHONE_STEP_INPUT_PHONE) {

    this.handleMobileInputType(nextMessage, nextInputType);
} else if (nextInputType === PHONE_STEP_INPUT_HYBRID) {

    this.handleHybridInputType(nextMessage, nextInputType);
}
```

}

Как лучше избавиться от дублирования componentWillReceiveProps в данном случае?

Comment: Базовый класс написать для них не пробовали?..

Comment: каким образом? может быть у вас есть пример какой-то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать high order component и вынести общую логику туда.

```
import React from 'react'

const withCommonLogic = Component => {
    return class extends React.Component {
          componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
              // общая логика
          }

          render() {
              return <Component {...this.props} />
          }
    }
}
```

Теперь достаточно обернуть нужный компонент в этот hoc

```
const MyComp = props => <div></div>

export default withCommonLogic(MyComp)
```

Comment: А если. У каждого контейнера своим mapStateToProps
 И  mapDispatchToProps
Куда их поместить?

Comment: @werty `connect` можно обернуть так же, `connect(...)(withCommonLogic(MyComp))`

Comment: @werty решение помогло?

Comment: да. спасибо....!!